# how to burn a live cd from bootable usb stick?

Tags: usb, live-usb, live-cd

I’ve a ubuntu 12.04 bootable usb. but i want to keep a live CD of the same. please tell me how to burn a live CD from bootable usb.

Comment: did you have .iso file

Comment: Usually people look for [Create a bootable Gentoo USB from within Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/672797/10425)

Answer (score 3):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdx of=<file_name>.iso
```

**Note**: Make sure that you replace the X with the right device number.

Once you have the ISO file, you can burn it to CD.   On a personal note, I would recommend that you download the ISO from Ubuntu if that is all possible, and burn the CD that way.