# Create a bootable Gentoo USB from within Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, live-usb, iso, bios, unetbootin

I am unable to create a Bootable USB for Gentoo, using Netbootin on Ubuntu.

How can I create a bootable USB using the `gentoo.iso` file?

Comment: Please describe what you mean by 'unable to create....using UNetbootin". What error are you getting? See http://askubuntu.com/questions/16277/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-from-a-iso-file

Comment: I am unabel to create boot-able USB stick Using UnetBootin

Comment: Can you describe the steps you have taken while trying to create a bootable USB stick using UNetbootin?

Comment: The answer to your second question is simple... your USB stick is probably FAT32 formatted.

Comment: FAT 32 has a built-in limitation, which will deny you to copy files 4GB or larger to the USB stick. The 6GB is this one file? If the 6GB are multiple files of less than 4GB you should have no problem copying.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid your copying problem reformat your USB stick to NTFS file system which does not have this 4GB limitation.

Comment: It was not asked like "copying problem", why should he shift to NTFS?

Answer (score 1):

### GUI solution

```
$ sudo apt-get install usb-creator-gtk
$ usb-creator-gtk
```

### Command Line solution

Replace `sdx` by the usb device:

```
$ sudo dd if=<file_name>.iso of=/dev/sdx
```